# Why are extern templates on standard library classes not allowed for basic types

Tags: c++, templates, extern

The std namespace [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#def:customization_point) has the following rule:

> A program may explicitly instantiate a class template defined in the standard library only if the declaration (a) depends on the name of at least one program-defined type and (b) the instantiation meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

Why does that rule exist?  If one wanted to extern, say `vector<int>` for instance, would a `typedef` over that `int` or a `struct` that contains the `int` be good enough?  I'm not sure whether the compiler/linker could simplify the `struct` back down to an `int`, but it would for the `typedef`.

Comment: i dont understand how `extern` is related to the quote

Comment: can you give a concrete example for what you think should be possible but is illegal due to that quote?

Comment: what does `typedef` have to do with explicit instantiation of templates? I second idclev463035818 show us what you think this quote prohibits because I have a feeling you are confusing things.

Comment: Because standard libraries may already provides such explicit instantiation.

Comment: Ah, I think I misread that rule.

Answer (score 1):

> extern

dosen't allow typenames, because typenames need to be compiled with the code while  extern stuff can be compiled later and linked.

and to answer your main question a typedef or something similar is possible if the code which is being compiled defines exactly which type it is no mather where in that code (of course with the correct syntax)

lastly
it is forbidden to compile undefined templates from std because there are librarys which wont work if you do that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by (a) "extern doesn't allow typenames", (b) "defines exactly which type it is no mather where in that code", and (c) "compile undefined templates from std"? The current wording seems very difficult to parse. I _think_ you mean that (a) `extern` can't be used with templates, (b) explicit instantiations with user-defined types are possible, and (c) one cannot explicitly instantiate with basic or `std` types because that might break other code somehow (ABI break? something else?). Are these readings along the right lines?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that rule is simply that the implementation might have provided a template specialization for a type that it knows about. Restricting user-defined specializations to user-defined types means that there cannot be any conflicts while allowing the standard library implementor flexibility (perhaps to provide optimized versions).